how to copy nested folders from sharepoint to azure adls?
I have nested folders inside a parent folder and each folder contains many files. I have used powerAutomate, but it only copies files from the folder at parent folder level. The files and the folders containing them are not copied. Is there a way i can copy the entire nested folder and files in them from sharepoint to ADLS ? I have also tried ADF, but it does not seem to work.

When a file changes or all files periodically?

when a file changes. its rare all the files gets updated at once.


how to copy nested folders from sharepoint to azure adls?

You can do that using  below Design:

Then:

SharePoint:

Output:


Hi Rithwik, Thanks for sharing the answer. In your answer you are moving the files from sharepoint list. Is there way to do this using sharepoint's document library ? I have my parent folder in sharepoint document
